# How to unit test setter method in Mockito JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following method.
 ***HttpServletRequest Request***

> Request.getSession().setAttribute("email", "some@email.com");

How can I unit test the method above with Mockito?

I would like to validate that method send or insert these two parameters.

**Update**

I wanted to verify or validate that

> Request

in Test method.

Comment: Sorry but it unclear to me what you are asking. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have to test some servlet I suggest this approach

```java
HttpServletResponse res = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
HttpServletRequest req = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpSession session = Mockito.mock(HttpSession.class);
Mockito.doReturn(session).when(req).getSession();

myHttpServlet.service(req, res);

Mockito.verify(req, Mockito.times(1)).getSession();
Mockito.verify(session, Mockito.times(1)).setAttribute(
        ArgumentMatchers.eq("email"), ArgumentMatchers.eq("some@email.com"));
Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(session, req);
```